# Overriding CSS inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, css, infusionsoft

I’m currently working on this page:
http://www.prosperitycapitaladvisors.com/become-a-prosperity-capital-advisor/ with an embedded javascript form called infusionsoft (iframe form) and my client asks me to make it responsive.

Is there a possible way to override the css or inject custom style inside the iframe form?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't override anything inside an iframe unless the owner provides some kind of API to do it.

Comment: Side note: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)